# How to anim element by scrolling from a specific point to another?

Tags: javascript

I would like to anim my element from 0 to 100 by scrolling from a starting point to an end point. More specifically, from the black thread to the green top div element.

[image: the screenshot]

Then, the goal is to create a circle that have a width and a height of 100vw.

Here is my javascript code :

```
    window.onscroll = function() {
  let scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  //halfSection7 is the breakpoint to start the animation (from the black thread);
  const halfSection7 = section7.offsetTop + (section7.clientHeight/2) - headerHeight;
  if (scrollPos>=  halfSection7)  {
    var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight ;
    var newHeight = height -  halfSection7 ;
    var scrolled = scrollPos  / halfSection7 ;
    document.getElementById("myBar").style.height = scrolled  + "vw" ;
    document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "vw" ;
    console.log(scrolled);
    if (scrolled >= 99) {
      document.getElementById("myBar").style.height = 100  + "vw" ;
      document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = 100 + "vw" ;

     }

  }
}
```

At the moment, my cirle goes from 1 to 1.10...

Thanks
Younes

---

Answer (score 0):

You're using vw even for the height value. Shouldn't it be vh ?